# Store directory location

Tags: c++

I am trying to store a directory location in ram so that I can access it later in my application. My goal is to achieve this snippet of code:

```
ContentManager.GetDir();
ContentManager.SetDir("../Content/");
```

I am puzzled at the moment and could use some help!

Comment: Variables are stored in RAM. What part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Store your path in a std::string or use boost::filesystem : http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Filesystem:

```
path dirLocation = "c:\\mydirectorylocation";
if(exists(dirLocation) && is_directory(dirLocation))
{
    std::string myPath = dirLocation.string();
}
```